# Django admin custom view and urls

Tags: python, django, url

I'm new to Django and I currently have two problems that I can't figure out from reading online:

1. URLs... I have an app 'cq' and the project is 'mysite' here is what I have in mysite's urls.py

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^cq/', include('cq.urls')),
       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   ]
   ```

and this is what I have in cq's urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^(?P<team_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.team, name='team'),
    ]
```

However I don't want do to cq/team_id. I just want to be able to go directly to /team_id. Is there any way to do it?

1. I want an entry in the admin view of the database to look very custom, i.e. I want to write my own html.. How do I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show your URL code, and explain exactly what isn't working. For the second question, you should read the documentation on [customizing the admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) and come back with any *specific* problems (in a separate question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define

```
url(r'^cq/', include('cq.urls')),
```

it means all urls in cq.urls will have to start with cq/. For you case, just do

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^cq/', include('cq.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^(?P<team_id>[0-9]+)$', views.team, name='team') #without trailing slash for /team_id, but with for /team_id/
]
```

Of course, you don't need this rule anymore in cq urls.py

Comment: thanks! I tried this before, but I just realized i had to import view from cq